# Design Time Data in Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10

While I can created some Design Time Sample Data in both WP8 Silverlight and Runtime App (Windows 8.1), I can't set them in my new Universal App (windows 10).

As what this man showed [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Windows/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-RTM/Improvements-to-XAML-data-binding) , Sample data'll simply show up both in design time and run time.

But when I try, It only shows the name of properties in design view.

Here is my code:

```
public class SampleModel
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri Image { get ;set;  } 
}

public class DesignTimeSampleModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SampleModel> SampleList { get; set; }


    public DesignTimeSampleModel()
    {
        SampleList = new ObservableCollection<SampleModel>;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            SampleList.Add(new SampleModel() { 
                 Name = "Design Data",
                 Image = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png", UriKind.Absolute);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in my MainPage

```
<Page
    xmlns:vm="using:UWP_Test_Binding.ViewModels"
    .......
>

<d:Page.DataContext>
    <vm:DesignTimeSampleModel/>
</d:Page.DataContext>

<Grid>            
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SampleList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource NameTextBlock}"/>                            
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" MaxHeight="50"/>
                </StackPanel>                        
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Even when I changed the datacontext in XAML like

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:DesignTimeSampleModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

or what i've done in WP8 silverlight

```
d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignInstance Type=vm:DesignTimeSampleModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"
```

or set context in code-behind

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new ViewModels.DesignTimeSampleModel();      
}
```

My sample data doesn't show in XAML view

[image]

Comment: what about INotifyPropertyChanged. I see thats missing in your model

Comment: Yeah I know that, but in the tutorial video that guy also missed that too.

Comment: ok.I realise since it is observable, that isn't required.

Comment: check this link, it is for vb but you can easily relate  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2015/05/22/win10-apps-in-net-design-time-data-in-xaml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy your code and create a new project to test it. There is an error in your view model:

> In this line:
>   SampleList = new ObservableCollection<SampleModel>;

Try this DesignTimeSampleModel:

```
public class DesignTimeSampleModel
  {
    public ObservableCollection<SampleModel> SampleList { get; set; }

    public DesignTimeSampleModel()
    {
      SampleList = new ObservableCollection<SampleModel>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        SampleList.Add(new SampleModel()
        {
          Name = "Design Data",
          Image = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png", UriKind.Absolute)
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's just my mistake when copy code to stackoverflow, In my project it's `SampleList = new ObservableCollection<SampleModel>();`, but it's still not work. Which version of VS did you use ?

Comment: Ah no, I mean "which version" here is community or pro or enterprise.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason but I can try it later.

Comment: FINALLY, I know why ! Downloaded pro version today and lost 3 hours to install, still got this error :((( and then I found out that set debug = x86 will fix this :) Really don't know why, but it worked. @@ It' look like VS team will have sth to fix in next update.